# Why won't these functions to find the longest and shortest word in an array work?

Tags: c

I'm writing this program where it takes 10 words and returns the longest and shortest word. I decided to write my own functions to do this.
I have no idea why they don't work. I get no errors **and no warnings**.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char words[10][100];
int i;
char shortestWord(char array[10][100]);
char longestWord(char array[10][100]);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Input ten words: \n");

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element %d \n", i + 1);
        gets(words[i]);
    }

    printf("The shortest word is:%c\n", shortestWord(words));

    printf("The longest word is:%c\n", longestWord(words));

    return 0;
}

 char shortestWord(char array[10][100])
 {
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(strlen(array[0]) > strlen(array[i]))
                strcpy(array[0], array[i]);
        }
    return array[0][100];
 }

char longestWord(char array[10][100])
 {
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(strlen(array[0]) < strlen(array[i]))
                strcpy(array[0], array[i]);
        }
    return array[0][100];
 }
```

For the shortest and longest word the program outputs a random character, like 'a' or something. It makes no sense.
If anyone can share something to help me solve this problem I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: you need to return the string, not a char

Comment: But string isn't a data type? How do I define the function then?

Comment: Do (e.g.) `char *longestWord(...)` and `return array[0]`. Change `printf` to use `%s`

Comment: Modifying the array (with strcpy) isn't a good idea. For example, if the longest string is in `array[0]` it will be overwritten when you call `shortestWord()` and then `longestWord()` won't return the correct value.

Comment: Yes that's the exact  problem I have left to solve. Could you please tell me what I can use as a substitute to strcpy? I tried to assign one value to the other, but couldn't because it is an array type.

Comment: Is the "random character" the first letter of the second word you entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my top comment:

> Do (e.g.) `char *longestWord(...)` and `return array[0]`. Change `printf` to use `%s`

---

Here's a corrected version that does that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char words[10][100];
int i;
char *shortestWord(char array[10][100]);
char *longestWord(char array[10][100]);

int
main(void)
{
    printf("Input ten words: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d \n", i + 1);
        char *cp = words[i];

        cp = fgets(cp,100,stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        cp = strchr(cp,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;
    }

    printf("The shortest word is:%s\n", shortestWord(words));
    printf("The longest word is:%s\n", longestWord(words));

    return 0;
}

char *
shortestWord(char array[10][100])
{
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (strlen(array[0]) > strlen(array[i]))
            strcpy(array[0], array[i]);
    }
    return array[0];
}

char *
longestWord(char array[10][100])
{
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (strlen(array[0]) < strlen(array[i]))
            strcpy(array[0], array[i]);
    }
    return array[0];
}
```

---

The above works but there are few things that could be tightened up.

*Never* use `gets`. It's a security hazard and the man page explains why.

There is *no* need to use `strcpy` in the search functions. Just remember the index of the shortest/longest and return a pointer to that element.

`strlen(array[0])` is loop *invariant* but the compiler can't know that. Better to have (e.g.) a `maxlen` variable that keeps track of that.

And, adding (e.g.) `curlen` allows for only one `strlen` call per loop iteration.

Also, you are "hardwiring" `10` for the array count and `100` for the max string length everywhere. Better to use some `#define`. This makes the code more flexible.

Anyway, here's how I would refactor the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCOUNT    10
#define MAXLEN      100

char words[MAXCOUNT][MAXLEN];

char *shortestWord(char array[MAXCOUNT][MAXLEN]);
char *longestWord(char array[MAXCOUNT][MAXLEN]);

int
main(void)
{
    printf("Input ten words: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXCOUNT; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d \n", i + 1);
        char *cp = words[i];

        cp = fgets(cp,MAXLEN,stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        cp = strchr(cp,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;
    }

    printf("The shortest word is:%s\n", shortestWord(words));
    printf("The longest word is:%s\n", longestWord(words));

    return 0;
}

char *
shortestWord(char array[MAXCOUNT][MAXLEN])
{
    int j = 0;
    size_t minlen = strlen(array[j]);
    size_t curlen;

    for (int i = 1; i < MAXCOUNT; i++) {
        curlen = strlen(array[i]);
        if (minlen > curlen) {
            j = i;
            minlen = curlen;
        }
    }

    return array[j];
}

char *
longestWord(char array[MAXCOUNT][MAXLEN])
{
    int j = 0;
    size_t maxlen = strlen(array[j]);
    size_t curlen;

    for (int i = 1; i < MAXCOUNT; i++) {
        curlen = strlen(array[i]);
        if (maxlen < curlen) {
            j = i;
            maxlen = curlen;
        }
    }

    return array[j];
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Hey man thanks a lot, that code works perfectly and I get pretty much all of it. The only thing I don't get is the "size_t" thing. Do you mind explaining why you used that specifically for this problem? I would really appreciate it thanks.

The `TL;DR`: `size_t` is the type that `strlen` returns, so it's natural to use it.

Most systems are 64 bit these days. But, there are still 32 bit systems around. In the "good ole days", `strlen` would have returned an `int` [or more correctly, `unsigned int`].

If we *know* we're using short [enough] strings we can use `int`. But, that is only 32 bits [usually].

On *really* old systems (e.g. 8086 PCs running MS/DOS), an `int` could be 16 bits. On those systems, a `long` was 32 bits.

So, back then, `strlen` might return `int` or `long`, depending upon the compiler and what `libc` would do.

With 64 bit systems, `strlen` would return `unsigned long`.

So, to standardize things, so one could write code that worked *regardless* of the above dependencies, a special `typedef` was defined: `size_t`.

`size_t` is *guaranteed* to be able to span the full address range of the architecture the code is being compiled for. And, thus, could contain the length of *any* string, even if the string was (e.g.) 300 GB long.

The [probable] definition of `size_t` would be:

```
typedef unsigned long size_t;
```

But, in the past, it *could* be one of: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, or `unsigned long`

The reason that I said *probable* is that most POSIX system compilers (e.g. `gcc`) define `long` to be a "floating" type that is 32 bits on a 32 bit architecture and 64 bits on a 64 bit architecture.

This is the `LP64` memory model that most OSes use.  See the table under the "TECHNICAL CHOICES" section of: http://archive.opengroup.org/public/tech/aspen/lp64_wp.htm `LP64` is compatible with `ILP32` which was used for 32 bit machines.

The recalcitrant outlier [of course ;-)] is ... Windows. It uses the `LLP64` model for 64 bit and `LP32` for 16/32 bit machines. When going to 64 bit, MS decided that because `int` had to remain 16 bits [a DOS legacy] and `long` was used to represent 32 bits, `long` *had* to remain 32 bits even on a 64 bit machine [and they defined a special/non-standard `typedef` to get a 64 bit number] to prevent zillions of lines of code from breaking.

Is your head spinning [yet] :-)?

Rather than the application programmer having to decide what size variable to use (e.g. 32 bit for 32 bit systems and 64 bit for 64 bit systems), the abstract type `size_t` was defined in a standard header file: `stddef.h`.

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot, that code works perfectly and I get pretty much all of it. The only thing I don't get is the "size_t" thing. Do you mind explaining why you used that specifically for this problem? I would really appreciate it thanks.